# In QtGUI who else calls the paint method?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qtgui

I'm using a QStyledItemDelegate in a QListView.

```
class ViewDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
   {
protected:
void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;

    initStyleOption(&opt, index);
    QImage image = index.model()->data(index.model()->index(index.row(), 0), Qt::ForegroundRole).value<QImage>();

    QStyle* style = opt.widget ? opt.widget->style() : QApplication::style();
    style->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &opt, painter, opt.widget);

    QRect rect = opt.rect;

    float zoomFactor = 1.0;

    // Zoom When Selected
    if (opt.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
    {
        zoomFactor = 1.5;
    }
    painter->drawImage(QRect(rect.left(), rect.top(), image.width() *zoomFactor, image.height()* zoomFactor), image);

}
```

With it being used as

```
QListView* listView = new QListView();
listView->setItemDelegate(new ViewDelegate());
```

The problem I'm having is that something is calling another paint method before this. As in I see both the default image that is painted and my scaled image on top of that.

Comment: Attach a debugger, put in a breakpoint, find out?

Comment: I've tried that but there has to be some other paint method being called int he library behind the scenes. I can't set a break point there.